# Windows removes quotes from target in shortcut

Tags: windows, cmd, shortcut

My shortcut target is: `%APP_HOME%\abc.bat`

The problem is that `%APP_HOME%` has spaces and when i save the shortcut, window's removes the double quotes and says it can't find the path. Now a requirement for me is the environment variable and to run the target with admin rights.

EDIT: `APP_HOME` is `C:\myFolder\my app folder\current`

it breaks due to the spaces in `my app folder`.

For those wondering, so far i've tried `"`, using `%20`, using`^` to escape spaces.

Comment: What about %20 instead of space?

Comment: @SagarV that was one of the first things i hoped would work, it sadly just output the text %20 lol, doesn't recognize it as a space.

Comment: how about C:\myFolder\"my app folder"\current

Comment: @Anil_M nope, also doesn't work. Breaks the `\`.

Comment: Works fine for me, without any quotes.  Windows 7.  Are you sure Explorer can see the environment variable in question?  Try logging out and back in.  And better double-check that it is in fact set correctly, e.g., by saying `cd %app_home%` on the command line.

Comment: @HarryJohnston `cd %APP_HOME%` takes me to `C:\myFolder\my app folder\current`. Does your environment variable have a space in it? It works fine for me as well when there are no spaces.

Comment: @HarryJohnston What's your' shortcut target?

Comment: The shortcut is to `%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Notepad++\notepad++.exe` which expands to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe`

Comment: @HarryJohnston Make a new environment variable and call it `%TEST_HOME%`, assign it the value `%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Notepad++`

then create a shortcut that points to `"%TEST_HOME%\notepad++.exe"`

this will work from the command the command line but not as a shortcut :)

The reason being that windows removes the stupid `"` and no longer properly parses the path :/

Comment: Nope, still works.  It removes the double-quotes, but it doesn't seem to need them.

Comment: @HarryJohnston now i'm getting irritated then lol. It doesn't work for me. Exactly as you typed it :/

works from cmd.exe but not as a shortcut.

Comment: Try using the Sysinternals Process Monitor (from the MS web site) to see what path Explorer is actually trying to run.  Also, what version of Windows are you running?

Comment: @HarryJohnston W10

Comment: @HarryJohnston can you do me a favor please, can you create a new folder and call it `My Apps`, then install notepad++ into it.

`C:\My Apps\Notepad++\notepad++.exe`

and your environment variable would be: `APP_HOME` = `C:\My Apps\Notepad++`

then your target in the shortcut would be `%APP_HOME%\notepad++.exe`

does that work?

Comment: Yes, I'm afraid it does.  Even on Windows 10.

Comment: @HarryJohnston Right click, shortcut tab, advanced, Run as administrator. This should break it.

Comment: ... not for Notepad++, but it is doing something weird when the target is a batch file and command-line arguments are present.  (I just get a command window popping up and immediately disappearing.)

Comment: @HarryJohnston yup, noticed that. I found a work around from the cmd.exe. Posted it below. Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: `"%APP_HOME%\abc.bat"`

Answer (score 0):

So i never found an answer for this on how to use an environment variable which contains spaces in a windows shortcut, i really hope someone can find an answer. For the moment, my work around is to use a windows cmd.exe shortcut that's run as administrator with the following target:

`C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /k cd %HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH% && "%APP_HOME%\abc.bat" -installdir "%APP_HOME%"`

**SOLUTION**: In my case i was trying to create a shortcut `abc.bat`, then i modified the target to be `"%APP_HOME%\abc.bat" -installdir "%APP_HOME%"`

but this failed because windows would remove the `"` and as a result it could not find the target. The solution is so simple that i didn't think of it.

`Right Click on Desktop` -> `New` -> `Shortcut` -> `Paste the Target that you want in there`

Windows will still remove the `"` but at least it will expand properly.

as for why? I have absolutely no idea but i hope someone can shed light on this in the future.

**THE PROBLEM w/ Solution** So it's not an actual solution because what i just realized is that this breaks when you go to `Advanced` and try to run as administrator. But if you run it with normal user permissions, it will expand properly. Which sadly goes back to the original band aid mentioned above, create a cmd.exe shortcut that runs as administrator and executes the bat file.

Comment: I think it's because you're defining an environment variable in the 'user scope' and not in the 'system scope'. As soon as you run as 'administrator' the user variable is not known to the administrator environment variables!